# jQuery dynamic table header size

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I am working on generating a table completely with jQuery. It is coming along nicely except for one aspect.  The width of the column headers is too large on some fields.

Note in the fiddle that the fields containing 'asdf', '1234', and '5678' are the proper width.
I would like for the fields with a longer string to also be that width. As of right now I am trying to set the width and height in a static manner.  I have noticed that the bigger the height, say like 1000px, will make the width proper, but I cannot have the columns that big.
How do I go about doing that?

```
th {
 width: 20px;
 height: 550px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michaela_elise/CFNHP/29/

Comment: Is the text going to be vertical?  This issue is directly related to the 'white-space: nowrap' property.  The table headers are still trying to accommodate the (horizontal) width of the spans, even though they are rotated vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the rotated spans have the width they would have if the text was not rotated. You could override this by specifying a width on the spans, and then the table will correctly adjust to fit them:

```
.r90 span {
 /* ... */
 width: 20px; /* <== Specify width here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you John. That definitely solves the width problem. How do I push the text down to the bottom?

Comment: @michaela_elise just set vertical-align: bottom; to your th elements